# Как правильно создать связь один к многим в таблицах PosgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Win 7/64. При создании базы параллельно пользуюсь pgadmin 4 1.3 и командами через psql. Первая таблица - список происшествий. Одна из её колонок содержит указание на тип происшествия (кража, угон машины и т.п.). В соседних колонках описание данного происшествия, дата и всякое другое. Чтобы избежать ввода некорректного текста в колонку с типом происшествия, надо сделать вторую таблицу, чтобы в ней были заданы типы происшествий. Ну и связать их отношением один к многим. Пробую так:

```
CREATE TABLE ee01.ex_types (
exid integer PRIMARY KEY,
ex_type varchar(50) REFERENCES ee01.ex_main (ex_type);
ex_descrip varchar(250)
);
```

Но таблица не создается, связь не формируется. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 момента:

1. `ex_type varchar(50) REFERENCES ee01.ex_main (ex_type);` в конце должна быть запятая, а не точка с запятой
2. Чтобы подобное сработало во  таблице ex_main параметр ex_type должен быть primary key

Если в таблице main primary key это какой либо id (ex_typeid например), то в создаваемой таблице лучше указывать этот id а не строковое представление, так как при создании бд стараются не дублировать информацию

Comment: спасибо, сейчас попробую разобраться.

Answer (score 0):

Данном случае у тебя много событий к одному типу. Соответственно колонка тип у тебя должна быть в таблице ex_main  и она будет ссылаться на ex_types. Так как у одного мейна один тип.

Comment: Колонка "ex_type" у меня в обоих таблицах. Но я не могу правильно задать эту ссылку.

Comment: У вас получается, что таблица ex_types использует значения из таблицы ex_main. А должно быть наоборот.

Comment: References нужно делать в таблице ex_main на поле exid таблицы ex_types.

Comment: @Bakhuss, спасибо увидел ошибку!

Answer (score 0):

В итоге повнимательнее почитал "[PostGIS in Action](http://opencarts.org/sachlaptrinh/pdf/20631.pdf)" (стр. 19-23), и получилось у меня так. Сначала:

```
CREATE TABLE ee01.ex_types (
exid char(5) PRIMARY KEY,
ex_type varchar(50),
ex_descrip varchar(250)
);
```

потом:

```
CREATE TABLE ee01.ex_main (
id serial PRIMARY KEY,
ex_type char(5) NOT NULL,
geom geometry(point,32641)
);
```

а потом:

```
ALTER TABLE ee01.ex_main
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_main_ex_types FOREIGN KEY (ex_type)
REFERENCES ee01.ex_types (exid) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT;
```

Связь получилась. Проверил в pgadmin - колонка ex_type в главной таблице ничего не принимает кроме заданных в таблице типов строк. Читайте железные книги, что называется... И такой момент. Может это всем уже хорошо известно, но для меня было новым. Когда создаешь таблицу в pgadmin, а потом тут же что-то в ней исправить через команды psql, то последний перестает выполнять команды, тупит...